# Configure Rollup.js so that it treats jQuery as already loaded

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dependencies, rollupjs

I'm working on a WordPress plugin and have no experience with JS bundlers yet, but need one. I decided to use rollup.js to get started because it seems to be easier to configure than the overpowering webpack.

In WordPress I have specified jquery as a dependency for my JavaScript, so my JavaScript only loads when jQuery is fully loaded.

How do I have to configure Rollup.js so that it takes into account that jQuery is already loaded?

Comment: Do you want to include jQuery in your bundle or treat it as an external dependency?